# Create property(?) for angular textarea component?

Tags: html, angular, components

I'm trying to create my own textarea component with auto-height OR a set height.
For example, right now I'm able to manually change between auto-height or set a value in the component itself (removing the auto-height code) but I would like to be able to do decide this in the "app.component.html" when I call this component.

Example:

**autotextarearesize.component.html**:

```
<textarea #textArea [style.height]="heigth" (input)="changeHeigth(textArea)" (blur)="heigth='5em'"> </textarea>
```

Now I'm calling the method "changeHeigth" which makes the height infinite. 
I can manually change this this to: (input)="this.heigth='5em'" in order to have a set-height.

Lastly this component as a whole is called in **app.component.html** as `<app-autotextarearesize></app-autotextarearesize>`.

I would like to achieve like a property setting so I can decide using for example `<app-autotextarearesize [Size]="Auto"></app-autotextarearesize>` or `<app-autotextarearesize [Size]="Height=10em"></app-autotextarearesize>` if possible.

My Angular knowledge is very limited and I'm not sure if this is possible to achieve the above? I'm aware of CdkTextareaAutosize and such but I'd like to create my own simple solution, even if not as good.

Also apologize for any faulty terminology usage. Trying to get a hang of it lol. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check @Input usage in angular. https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Comment: I will have a look, cheers!